# query : how to get the value of a custom field within a relationship field?

Tags: relationships, query, query-module

I have a channel 1 and a channel 2.
In channel 1 I have a relationship field that relate to channel 2.

I want (by making a query, for reasons I won't explain here because this is not important) to trace the content of a custom field (named "client") of the channel 2.

I know I have to look into `exp_relationships` table but don't know how to build my query because the columns of `exp_relationships` are not very relevant to me :D

What I have as material to use at this stage is the ID of the parent entry.

Anyone can help me on this please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any luck using my sweet answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exp_relationships` table’s two relevant columns are `parent_id` and `child_id`. In your example, the `entry_id` of the entry in Channel 1 is the `parent_id` and the `entry_id` from Channel 2 is the `child_id`.

So you’ll build your query by selecting fields from the `exp_channel_data` table, joining to `exp_relationships` via the `child_id`, and specifying the entry via the `parent_id`. I’m using SequelPro, and something like this appears to do the trick…

```
select field_id_N 
from exp_channel_data 
inner join exp_relationships on exp_channel_data.entry_id = exp_relationships.child_id
where exp_relationships.parent_id = NNN
```

There are variations. Let’s say you are looking for the `title` of the child entry, you can skip the `exp_channel_data` table and go straight for the jugular by linking to the `exp_channel_titles` table instead, like this…

```
select title 
from exp_channel_titles 
inner join exp_relationships on exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_relationships.child_id
where exp_relationships.parent_id = NNN
```

Comment: sorry I tested it yesterday and it worked perfectly as you said. Thank you. The thing is that I'm searching now to reach the title of the child entry...(not easy for me :D )

Comment: There you go, that edit should get you all the way home.